# Can't update (404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80])

Tags: networking, apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

I'm running ubuntu on a raspberry pi 4 (8GB) and I cannot for the life of me get it to update because I think it can't find 91.189.91.38 80 for some reason even though I can go there through my browser just fine. I've been trying to fix this for ages. But 90% of the posts are super old and don't work and some people mention some things with a router but don't say what needs to be done and it's driving me nuts.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Ign:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty InRelease
Hit:2 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal InRelease
Get:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]
Get:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]
Get:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease [265 kB]
Get:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty Release [58.5 kB]
Get:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty-updates/main Sources [431 kB]
Get:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [1089 kB]
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
Get:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [1355 kB]
Get:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [1355 kB]
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty-security/main i386 Packages
Err:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Ign:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty-security/main i386 Packages
Err:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Get:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe arm64 Packages [8458 kB]
Get:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe i386 Packages [4642 kB]
Get:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe i386 Packages [4642 kB]
Get:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe i386 Packages [4642 kB]
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty/main i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty/main i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe i386 Packages
Err:19 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe i386 Packages
Err:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Fetched 456 kB in 7s (63.4 kB/s)                                               
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard or public support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: Your sources relating to *trusty* are for an EOL/ESM release and off-topic here, but them being EOL/ESM is also likely related to your issue. Your issues is you've corrupted your sources, and you should clarify what release you actually think you're running (if it's *focal* then remove all *trusty* sources... and don't forget *arm* architecture cannot run much i386 as the *intel/amd* processors differ to *arm* in architecture)

Comment: I've changed the sources but no matter what sources I use it doesn't work. This is the OS I'm running:

Comment: ```NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Comment: Well remove all *trusty* lines from your sources.  20.04 is *focal*, where as *trusty* refers to 14.04 which is now EOL with regards the LTS release, and 14.04 ESM whilst still supported via Ubuntu Advantage is still off-topic here.

Comment: Why are you using `i386` with http://ports.ubuntu.com? Ports is/was for the non-i386/amd64 architectures, like armhf and the like.